# Data annotations working for some property of view model only

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have the following view model:

```
public class ClientViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Surname is required")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And the cshtml:

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Client information</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, new SelectList(ViewBag.TitleList, "Text", "Value"), "Title")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have the following issues:

- The required annotation is working only for the `Email` field and not for `Name` and `Surname` field.
- The error message displayed when Email field is empty, is not the error message I have put in the view model.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The rendered html for Email and Surname field is:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Surname">Surname</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Surname" name="Surname" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Surname" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Email">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="email" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see for Email, we have the data-val-required attribute but not for Surname field.

Comment: I think you might be overriding the validation message itself, try to do ```@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.<property>)``` (without the extra parameters) and see if the errormessage becomes visible ([see msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_6)).

Comment: @tabby - are these HTML tags are part of `form`?

Comment: @user1672994 : Yes they are.  As I said the data annotation is working for the email field but not for the name and surname field.